# передача массива в функцию без размера

Tags: c++

Как передать массив в функцию, не передавая его размер?

Comment: я слышал что можно еще с помощью шаблона както

Answer (score 5, accepted):

если интересует именно передача размера с помощью шаблонной функции, то так

```
template<std::size_t N> void f(int (&arr)[N]) 
{
   // N содержит количество элементов в переданном массиве
}

int main()
{
   int arr[5]={0};
   f(arr);
   return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** как такого понятия передача массива в функцию не существует. Вместо этого, мы можем передать массив в функцию двумя способами

- через указатель
- через ссылку на массива

Шаблонная функция `f` принимает случай передачи массива через ссылку.  Рассмотрим наш пример. Давайте попробуем переписать нашу функцию, убрав в определении шаблон. Учитывая, что мы передаем в качестве параметра функции массив размером из 5 элементов, то функция `f` будет выглядеть следующим образом

```
   void f(int (&arr)[5]) 
    {

    }
```

если будет передаваться массив, размером из 4 элементов, то мы должны определить функцию следующим образом

```
void f(int (&arr)[4]) 
{

}
```

И так далее. 
То есть объявление функций идентично, кроме размера передаваемого массива. Поэтому мы его шаблонизируем и его параметр будет принимать размер передаваемого массива.

При передаче массива через ссылку, функция должна определить размер массива. Определить размер массива очень просто.

```
int a[5];
n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
```

Определение размера выполняется за кулисами.

Comment: можете обяснить что происходит

Comment: @nikita2002, обновил ответ.

Comment: как параметр шаблона сам добавляется?

Comment: мы же не пишем когда передаем `int<5> arr`

Comment: @nikita2002, параметр шаблона не добавляется, мы его сами добавили в определение функции. Если при передаче массива в функцию вычислить не получиться, будет ошибка компиляции

Answer (score 2):

Передавайте, как указатель, тогда размер точно НЕ будет передан.

Но если вы хотите передать его так, чтобы функция знала, сколько там элементов - то либо надо передавать размер отдельно, либо использовать не массив, а класс типа `std::vector` или `std::array`, либо делать шаблонную функцию.